# What is the dual of "vectorial Radon measures such that its divergence is a Radon measure"?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, dual-spaces

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a compact of $\mathbb{R}^d$, let $\mathcal{M(X)}$ be the space of Radon measures defined as the topological dual of the space of continuous functions.

Consider now the space of vector Radon measures, denoted $\mathcal{M(X)}^d$. Any $\nu \in \mathcal{M(X)}^d$ has a divergence $\text{div}(\nu) = \sum_{i=1}^d \partial_i \nu$ which might or might not be a Radon measure i.e. $\text{div}(\nu) \in \mathcal{M(X)}$.

I'm looking for any functional analysis tools helping me to find the dual (or predual whatever) of the space $\left\{\nu \in \mathcal{M(X)}^d, \text{s.t. }  \text{div}(\nu) \in \mathcal{M(X)}\right\}$.

Comment: This question needs more information. Can you define what a vector Radon measure means? Is this a vector where each component is a Radon measure? I assume you are defining the divergence in terms of weak derivatives. How do you want the boundary handled in that weak derivative?

Comment: yes, here more details: a vector Radon measure is a linear form on the space of continuous functions on $\mathcal{X}$ with values in $\mathbb{R}^d$. I think you can roughly see it as a vector where each component is a Radon measure. The divergence is defined in the distribution sense, so the divergence of a vector Radon measure is always a distribution (but we want to look at the more peculiar case where it's a Radon measure). Concerning the boundary and since we look at a compact, I don't have any prior on the boundary

Comment: Looking at this again, there are more fundamental issues here. Suppose that $d=1$ and $\mathcal{X}$ is the Cantor set. What is your definition of the divergence? Even that gets sorted out, I don't know how to think about this problem without boundary conditions. Are you sure you don't mean to work with finite measures on all of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and then restrict attention to those with support in a given compact set? The standard distribution theory defines weak derivatives in this case, but not the other.